# script to process a list of ip addresses from a txt file and then confirm whether they are accessible or responding IPs within a excel file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-re

would like to be able to python script to process a list of ip addresses from a txt file and then confirm whether they are accessible or responding IP Addresses within a excel file.

I have seen the following,which I have used as a base but doesn't seem to work or work as I would expect;

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/extract-ip-address-from-file-using-python/

Comment: Please follow the rules of SO when requesting assistance: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: well i was going somewhere along the lines of; import re
import csv

f = open('C:/Users/dir/dir/iplogs.txt', 'r') #Text file with many ip address
o = f.read()
ip1 = re.findall( r"\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}", o )
hosts = ip1
for host in hosts:
               however then I couldnt quite figure out how to manage this from here.

Comment: That isn't readable. Add your code to the question please.